# Bluetooth LE CanUpdate Characteristic property

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building a `Xamarin.Forms`cross platform mobile app, which uses [`Monkey.Robotics`](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Getting%20Started/Mobile_Stack) for its Bluetoth Low Energy functionality. I am connecting to an `mbed` based implimentation of a [custom GATT service](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_GATT_Example/).

In the Xamarin C#, What triggers the Characteristic.`CanUpdate` property in Monkey.Robotics?

This is a standard example my C# is based on:

```
if (characteristic.CanUpdate) {
                characteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, e) => {
                    Debug.WriteLine("characteristic.ValueUpdated");
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
                        UpdateDisplay(characteristic);
                    });
                    IsBusy = false; // only spin until the first result is received
                };
                IsBusy = true;
                characteristic.StartUpdates();
            }
```

This has been working, but since I changed to my own custom GATT service which I am connecting to, the CanUpdate property is always false. What is this property and how is it triggered? This will really help me debugging my GATT service code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Monkey.Robotics](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/f6a878571a68ca5a324def55f1d62c1dd48463e8/Source) is open source, so you can just look it up yourself

CanUpdate is implemented like this:

```
public bool CanUpdate {

  get {
    return (this.Properties & CharacteristicPropertyType.Notify) != 0;
  }
}
```